# How to name a BrowserStack session with Cucumber Scenario name?

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, browserstack

I've 10 Cucumber Scenarios and I execute them on BrowserStack using Jenkins. Post execution, all my 10 scenarios will be updated with same name which we configured in capabilities.

Is there a way to name each session with the respective Cucumber scenario name so that it'll be easy for to identify the session of a respective scenario ?

I tried to read Cucumber scenario name using `scenario.getName()` but unable to pass it to Jenkins file where I configure my BrowserStack capabilities.

Comment: Hi You can use this JavaScript executor provided by BrowserStack in each of your scenario

Link- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/set-name-and-status-of-test

I hope this helps.

Else create a ticket for them by sending your query to support@browserstack.com

Comment: Thank you @HomeLander I'm able to rename the session name during run time